# .net series of gen 2 garbage collections

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I'm experiencing the case that GC Gen 2 collections happen in a series - straight after each other which makes my app hang for up to 30 seconds. This happens mostly when doing a GUI operation like starting an animation or navigating to another site (unloading and loading a new control.) It happens randomly. Meanwhile there is no Gen 2 collection at all. Setting LatencyMode to low before doing a navigation and setting it back after it's done didn't help much.

Facts:

- .net 4.0, WPF
- Gen 0 Heap size between 3 and 6 MB
- Gen 1 Heap size between 0 and 3 MB
- Gen 2 Heap size rather constantly ~330 MB
- LOH Heap size rather constantly ~70 MB

Gen 2 and LOH is that big because I'm caching many objects in dictionaries in order to access them in my time critical app very quickly.

I also have got a good perfmon screenshot but am not allowed to post it (SO spam prevention of new users) :(

Any ideas?

[image: PerfMon]

Comment: Can you upload the image somewhere and share a link? We can then edit it into the question for you. (Or if you manage to get one more upvote, the restrictions will be removed)

Comment: great, the upload of the image worked now

Comment: Did you consider keeping the objects and recycling them instead of removing them from the dictionaries? that way there are no new allocations and subsequently no garbage collections.

Comment: I asume you are talking about the usercontrols that are loaded. I could not to throw them away but keep and reuse a reference. But does this explain why the GC Gen 2 is three times collected right after each other and releasing no memory? Or the multiple collects when starting an animation? This happens acually only at the first exeution of an animation.